# Building Sqoop 1.4.7 fails class SqoopVersion not found

Tags: sqoop

I'm trying to build Sqoop 1.4.7 from source and the build is failing.

```
org.apache.sqoop.SqoopVersion cannot be resolved to a type
```

There is no SqoopVersion.java file in the org.apache.sqoop package.

I've tried both the 1.4.7 branch and the trunk.

Anyone know what the magic is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. SqoopVersion.java gets generated under build/src.

I was trying to load this into Eclipse and after running ant I needed to add build/src as an additional src folder.